# python36.dll - Program has stopped working, a problem caused the program stop working correctly

Tags: python, windows, event-log

I have a created a python to get input files from windows folder and updated the excel sheet every 15 minutes. Program is always open - running in background.

Program was running properly for 2 weeks and suddenly the program closed with error message 'A problem caused the program stop working correctly and was closed". I have checked the log files and didn't see any error message.

I checked the Windows log viewer and error was present with below text, which i could not interpret properly. Can anyone please let me the possible causes for the error.

> Program.exe
>
> 0.0.0.0
>
> 5a2e9e81
>
> python36.dll
>
> 3.6.5150.1013
>
> 5abd3161
>
> c00000fd
>
> 0000000000041476
>
> 1ba8
>
> 01d45e9fe43cba57
>
> C:\Python code\program.exe
>
> C:\Users\aisteam\AppData\Local\Temp\2_MEI51602\python36.dll
>
> a9da018c-e2e3-4821-9387-cce82ff29186

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging (to file) to your code so you can see afterwards what it last did before it died? If you haven't tried that, what have you tried?

Comment: The excel file isn't open in Excel, is it? That's the most likely head slaps palm problem.

Comment: Excel file was still open. It was updating the excel sheet. Then it failed in the middle. I will try to get info and monitor the progress.

Comment: Head slaps palm.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your python code robustly handles errors like when the file it wants to update is locked, which is what Excel does while the file is open in Excel. by design, you could easily make your code create a new excel file each time, or wait until the file isn’t locked then update it. Either way, you need to make your code better at telling you what it is doing, e.g. by logging what it is doing (which is important to implement now because the logging needs to be in place *before* your code stops unexpectedly for, err, an unexpected reason), e.g. by carefully managing exceptions (i.e. don’t simply code as try/except:pass!)

BUT don’t do this sort of code with an unconditional except and nothing but a pass in the except: statement) because it will make errors HARDER to figure out:

`try:
        something
    except:
        pass`

Always be specific about the exception you expect, and even if you are going to not raise, always always always log the exception.